# Get unique fields list in grafana LogQL

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail, logql

My query :

> ({job="spring-service"} | json | url = "/user/login")

I'm trying to get all the unique user id's from logs and not the count.
But I couldn't, its easy to get count of the fields.

Comment: How is your log formatted?